# cascading last level is multiselect?

Tags: javascript

I have a cascading parameter it works fine, now at last level I tried with multi-select, so I hide two selections and then get its id and I have done some script, but it's not working.

Selection Relationship are:

```
103---10123,10298,10345

112---10124,10278,10346

121--10103,10158,10309,10325

131--10107,10248,10292,10329

<script>
    window.onload = function() 
    {
      document.getElementById('2').style.visibility="hidden";
      document.getElementById('3').style.visibility="hidden";

      if(window.addEventListener) 
      {
        document.getElementById('2').addEventListener('resize', getOrders, false);
      }
      else if(window.attachEvent) 
      {
        document.getElementById('2').attachEvent("onresize", getOrders);
      }

      if(window.addEventListener) 
      {
        document.getElementById('1').addEventListener('change', fire, false);
      }
      else if(window.attachEvent) 
      {
        document.getElementById('1').attachEvent("afterchange", fire);
      }
    }
<script>
```

[js fiddle for reference](http://jsfiddle.net/senthil4040/xT65n/)

Comment: Your question is not clear at all

Comment: for instance am having a cascading parameter with single level now from that i have to take it to last level must be multi-select..so i had hide level and try to bring in multi-select????